# Generate one-time offline numeric code for online application

Tags: random, one-time-password

I need to generate a one time numeric code from a board, this code must be validated from an online web application which if the token is valid will log it inside its database.

The generation of the token must of course be unpredictable from the user who simply clicks a button on the board and gets a generated token back.

The online application must be able to verify the token without communicating with the board directly.

What algorithm can the board and the web application use? Are there similar examples on the web?

Notice the board may be out of sync with the web service (i.e. User pressed the button 6 times and generated 6 tokens) and the web service must be able to verify them nonetheless.

The algorithm must be simple enough to be implemented in Arduino for instance and in the future even straight inside integrated circuits.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't believe I'm following the issue. If you're just looking for a way to generate a random number securely, how does this relate to AES? Sure AES should use random numbers for data encryption, but AES is certainly not a random number generator. Are you seeking a random number generator or a whole encryption system?

Comment: A random token generator and a token verifier which verifies them without communicating with the generator, ignore AES...

Comment: Sorry for replying back to your comment so late. Actually your comment about AES sparked an interesting thought for me. What about generating your random number, appending a delimiter to the end of the string version of the number, and then appending a plaintext sentinel value. You could then take that string and RSA encrypt it. The output of the RSA encryption would be your token. If the token can be successfully decrypted and contains the sentinel value, then the token is genuine and the first portion of the message (before the delimiter) is the random number which was generated.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite get your solution, consider however I'm talking about an AVR attiny generating a number of max 10 digits, RSA inside it would be already too much.

Comment: Ahh my apologies, Ms. Ferguson. Looking back on my comment posted many months ago, I too agree that it is not a decent approach for your circumstance. Tell me though, would your board be able to support the CRC32 hash function? Unfortunately, I am not the most knowledgeable about Arduino, so please forgive my lack of knowledge in that area.

Comment: CRC32 should be error correction, if you can elaborate on a solution using CRC32 I'm very curious about it.

Comment: Rather simple, it's about the same process as personne3000 recommended, but CRC32 outputs a 32 bit (4 byte) hash. Those 4 bytes can be represented in 8 hexadecimal characters which would leave you room to concatenate a 2 character identifier indicating what salt(s) you used in the CRC32 hash. I only mention it because I would think a SHA1 HMAC might be a little resource intensive for an Attiny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a secret password p, that you save in your token generator and your token verifier.

The token generator generates a random number N, and concatenates it with hmac_sha1(N, p). For more information about HMAC, have a look at [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code). Your token will have the format randomNumber_hmac, and look like:

0123456_0xfbdb1d1b18aa6c08324b7d64b71fb76370690e1d

Then your receiver can parse this token to extract the random number (here 0123456) and calculate hmac_sha1(0123456, p). If it matches the HMAC given in the token, it means that it was generated by someone that knows p... Which should be the token generator.

Those are pointers. Better security could be achieved (using a hash instead of just a random number is a first step), but this should already be quite solid. As long as there is some strong random component in the first part of the token, you can also concatenate it with additional data. Using a UUID for example, you can be 100% (with just a bit of rounding) sure that a different token is generated each time, and the token verifier can check that each token is used only once.

Comment: Just tossing this out there, it's unsafe to put the "secret" salt/pepper (`p`) inside of the token generator. Once you put it in the generator, it's really a public salt/pepper.

Comment: It is of course not safe but safe enough for my application once it is written in an embedded Attiny soldered to the board.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at HOTP (RFC 4226) or TOTP (RFC 6238) algoritms. This algorithms is a standard for One-time password generation.

Also, I can advise you not to invent the wheel and use comprehensive and secure solution from one of the world known strong authentication providers: [Vasco](https://vasco.com), [Protectimus](http://protectimus.com/en/),
RSA (couldn't google it from the first try).
All they have wide choice of special secure devices for OTP-generation and software to check it. 
The price of the device isn't so much to invent your own one, for example, Protectimus offers TOTP-compliant devices from $7 (solution's page). 
You can by one of them, of course if you haven't some extra special requirements

Comment: I need to create a simple algorithm inside an AVR attiny or little more, so a strong authentication chip would be too much.

Comment: If you can use any hash-function inside your chip then it's available to generate OTP as @personne3000 suggested. Algorithms described above in my answer use the same principle.